# Bind youtube event to Hangout on air

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

Please, help me out. Here is an outline of what I am trying to do.

1) Create an event
2) Bind it to a stream
3) Bind the event to Google Hangouts on Air
4) Get link to Hangouts
5) Invite participants

All this I want to create via API.

I manage to create event and bind it to a stream but it is not Hangout on Air type.

With new LiveStreaming API I can create an event and bind it to a stream, which I did but I can nowhere see options to bind this newly created event to the Hangouts on Air. 
However, I can easily create it via Youtube console (choosing 'Quick' type) and it will prompt me to open a Hangout app.

Is there anyway to do the same steps via API and get a hangout link?

Comment: Crash did you manage to do it?

Comment: ya crash did you manage to do this

Comment: also wondering if you managed to do this.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37979700/130638